# How to use color dropdown in sublime ?

Tags: css, sublimetext3

I love using sublime and basically love the color picker plugin , but i wanted something thats like a dropdown of awesome colors and whenever i am filling a `color` or `background-color` , this drop down appears , Brackets code editor has this feature built in i beleive , but in sublime i found **[THIS](https://github.com/idleberg/CSS-Colors)**, package.

But how do i go about using this package ? i have installed it but it seems to have no effect at all ?  How do i use a color drop down in sublime , This plugin would have been really useful for me to whip out quick demos , but it does't seem to work for me . can anybody explain why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that that package is something that does what have in mind. It also hasn't been updated in a couple of years. It sounds like you might want something more like this.

[ColorPick](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ColorPick)

I hope it helps!

Comment: I use windows :) , i had seen that plugin , basically want a dropdown of pritty colors not a color picker :D